# Date Picker XAMARIN FORMS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

```
<DatePicker x:Name="StartDatePckr" Format="ddd dd MMM"  DateSelected="Handle_DateSelected" />
```

I am using a simple Date Picker in my Xamarin forms Project. 
When the Picker is displayed, Today's date is selected by default.
Without changing the default selected date i want to click on "Done" and capture this Date. An event is fired only when i change the date but how do i achieve the above situation ?

SPECIALLY IN XAMARIN FORMS - ANDROID

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like specially for android(until you use custom render) it going to work across plateforms.  You can give date to `DatePicker` like this

```
<DatePicker x:Name="datePicker" Date="{x:Static system:DateTime.Today}" />
```

use namespace in your xaml in order to get date

```
xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

& fetch date from it like this without firing `DatePicker` events

```
var datePickerDate = datePicker.Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained here (https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/47570/datepicker-dateselected-event-not-fired-if-the-date-doesnt-change) along with `DateSelected="Handle_DateSelected"` add `Unfocused="Handle_DoneClicked"` to XAML element and process your special case there:

```
private void Handle_DoneClicked(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    //todo: process your special case here..
}
```

Comment: Well in that case, how am i suppose to distinguish between a "Done" and a "Cancel".

Comment: There's no difference as long you just use the default date that is not changing.